# Webview is blank / white in Android API 21

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, android-webview

I am making an application with a webview as the main content but when I run the application in API 21 (Android 5.0) the activity is blank but in API 30 the webview loads the web

This is my code in case something is wrong

```
webClient =findViewById(R.id.WebView);
        WebSettings settings = webClient.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webClient.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return false;
            }
        });
        webClient.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: any solution for this? problem with api 21-23